# Is a sentence in $\Pi_1$ true given $Q \vdash \lnot\varphi$?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, proof-theory

If $Q \vdash \lnot\varphi$ (Q is the Robinson arithmetic), and if I assume that $\varphi \in \Pi_1$; Can I say that $\varphi$ is a true sentence?

My thoughts are that, given that Q is $\Sigma_1$- complete, and that $Q \vdash \lnot\varphi$, I can say that $ \lnot\varphi$ is a true $\Sigma_1$ sentence($Q \vdash \lnot\varphi$ would imply that $\varphi$ is true in Q).

I also know that $\varphi \in \Delta_0 $ iff $\lnot \varphi \in \Delta_0$(Not exactly sure why?) then I could extand that to $\exists x \varphi \in \Delta_0$ iff $ \lnot\exists x \varphi \in \Delta_0$, which is then $\varphi \in \Sigma_1$ iff $\lnot \varphi \in \Pi_1$. But here is where i get stuck, what does this information tell me about whether $\phi$ is true given that $\varphi \in \Pi_1$, and $\lnot \varphi$ is true and  $\in \Sigma_1$.

Comment: If $\Bbb N\models Q$ and $Q\vdash\lnot\varphi$, then what is the truth value of $\varphi$ in the standard model?

Comment: You're confusing ($\Sigma_1$-)completeness with soundness, which is what you need to conclude that $\neg\varphi$ (not $\varphi$) is true if it is a formal theorem (for $\varphi$ of any complexity).

Comment: I'm confused by this question. Why would Q proving $\lnot$$\psi$ mean that somehow $\psi$ is true, instead of false?

Comment: Well, I also came to that conclusion, that is  $ \lnot\psi$ is true, but in my lecture notes, it says that $\psi$ is true. Being new to logic, it made me uncertain ...